# show data only if currentmonth and currentyear are larger than

Tags: php, date, if-statement

Let say currentmonth is 06 and currentyear 2017

i have dropdown of year and month ..
if i select year 2017 and month of July which is larger then currentmonth
how do i show there is not data available yet

my current code..and its not working..i'm a newbie and not sure im doing this right or not...

```
$mystartingyear=2017;
$mystartingmonth=01;

$currentmonth=date("m");
$currentyear=date("Y");

if ($currentyear >= $mystartingyear && $currentmonth >= $mystartingmonth)
{
echo "Show Data";
}
else
{
echo "No Data yet";
}
```

i also tried it like this

```
$mystartingyear=2017;
$mystartingmonth='01';

$currentmonth=12;
$currentyear=2017;

//$currentmonth=date("m");
//$currentyear=date("Y");

if ($currentyear >= $mystartingyear && $currentmonth >= $mystartingmonth)
{
echo "Show Data";
}
else
{
echo "No Data yet";
}
```

it always display "show data"

Comment: `echo "Show Data":` is incorrect you need to use semicolon `;`

Comment: @skunkhaze Haha. Good eye.

Comment: @Chris Burton lol i cant trust my eyes so i always execute code to check it

Comment: i have edited it but still not working ..the if statement i think is wrong how do i correct this

Comment: `01` is treated as an octal.

Comment: @blackrx You should be posting your full code for this; something is failing somewhere. I've submitted an answer and made an edit to it, if you haven't seen it. If you have, then you'll need to reload it.

Comment: Is this literally all the code you have? How are you getting the `$mystartingyear`, etc from the dropdown? You are showing us a hardcoded version.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

Integers from `01` to `07` are ok just as long as you don't do `010` (with 3 integers) since that will be represented as `8`. But as soon as you start hitting `08` and `09` for the months of August and September (which may be what's in your *unknown dropdown*), you will have problems.

So it's best you quote it.

- Consult "Footnotes".

---

*Original answer:*

The leading zero in `01` for:

```
$mystartingmonth = 01;
                   ^^
```

is treated as an octal.

It needs to be quoted:

```
$mystartingmonth = '01';
```

Octals references:

- http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal

---

**Footnotes:**

If your current code is failing you, then something else is failing you.

You mention in your question that you're using this from a dropdown and that code wasn't included, nor how it's being passed.

Use PHP's error reporting, set to catch and display:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Verify your conditional statement's logic also; both conditions **must** be met.

Comment: Good answer based on the unknown at this point. @blackrx you should update the question with more code.

Comment: @blackrx that doesn't tell me much really. I tested this myself just not with a dropdown. I asked you in comments to post your full code.

Comment: @ChrisBurton Thanks Chris. I seem to have fallen into a bit of rabbit hole here *lol* I might end up deleting it.

Comment: Haha. Not much to go on, quite frankly.

Comment: @ChrisBurton I'm afraid not, *sigh*.

Answer (score -2):

There is missing semicolon after first echo i.e. code should be

```
echo "Show Data";
```

Then every thing should work fine,

The  date(); function in php returns the date in string and when you compare a string with integer it is implicitly converted into equivalent integer variable,if you want for sure you can use intvar(); function which converts variable to equivalent integer.But in your case it is not necessary.For more about i recommend you to read [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) .

Comment: you needed to look at their edit; they already fixed that before your posting this